# check ProxyEnable in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I currently have two batch files:
proxy_enable.bat

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" ^
    /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

and proxy_disable.bat

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" ^
    /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

I would like to make only one file which would be proxy_switch.bat and that would be:

```
if (registry key is 0) (put it to 1) ELSE (put it to 0)
```

But I can't find a way to read the `ProxyEnable` key that is in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script should toggle the value, each time it is run:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "Fnd=%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe"
Set "Reg=%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe"
Set "Key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
Set "Val=ProxyEnable"
Set "Typ=REG_DWORD"

%Reg% Query "%Key%" /V "%Val%" | %Fnd% "x0" 1>NUL && (
    %Reg% Add "%Key%" /V "%Val%" /T %Typ% /D "1" /F 1>NUL
) || %Reg% Add "%Key%" /V "%Val%" /T %Typ% /D "0" /F 1>NUL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable" | find /i "0x0" && goto :set1
:set0
set it here to 0
goto :end
:set1
set it here to 1
:end
```

Comment: Could you explain the query? I'm not sure I fully understand it and it doesn't seem to be working :/ The commands I've posted do work though. Not sure what went wrong.

Comment: small error in my typing  - now corrected

Comment: reg query will query  a specific reg value and show you how its set